# How can I change an Image in libgdx?

Tags: image, libgdx, textures

I load an Image via Texture

```
texture = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
texture2 = new Texture("badlogic2.png");
image=new Image(texture);
stage.addActor(image);
```

or TextureRegion

```
texture = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
regions=new TextureRegion[2];
regions[0]=new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 0, 64, 64);
regions[1]=new TextureRegion(texture, 0, 63, 64, 64);
image=new Image(regions[0]);
stage.addActor(image);
```

Now, I want to change the `image` to `texture2` or `regions[1]`. How can I do that?

Comment: ok technically you use this: `image.region = regions[xNumber]` but for an image to create one don't you use: `image = new Image("myImage", regions[xNumber])` I might be wrong on that last one, but the first thing I put should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it didn't worked. There is no constructor Image(String, TextureRegion). This is Libgdx.

Comment: Yes I'm sorry, you're right, but did the first part work?

Comment: No, it isn't. There is no method .region :(